# How to remove files starting with dot (.) from a directory?

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of files and folders inside a directory. For example, .jazz or .project file after a checkout.

I am using batch script currently, May I know how to remove .jazz or .project files from my Jenkins workspace ?

Comment: `DEL /S /Q ".jazz*"`.

Comment: Just so we are clear the file name starting with a dot is really irrelevant to your question. Ultimately you just need a file mask that matches the file names you want to delete.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just like @Squashman said in the comments, you can use the wildcard symbol `*` combined with anything.

So in your case it is: `del /f ".jazz*"` Use `del /f /s ".jazz*"` if there are directories too.

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/del) for more information.